# Why I am getting Composer detected issues composer require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl?

Tags: php

I am new to php.

I have installed XAMPP.

I have a config file.

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'registration');
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

First Error I am getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()
```

Then I tried to enable the extension in php.ini file

```
extension=mysqli
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=openssl
```

Now I am getting when running on browser http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli, openssl
```

Comment: @Phil yes running a url

Comment: @Phil yes it means opening in browser

Comment: Where do you see the errors? Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71345268/edit) to provide a screenshot for context?